# Lookup field doesn't show all records when you start typing in the field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, on a contact lookup when you start typing in the lookup field, the auto complete only shows those contacts which recently have been used. For example, there are 2 contacts Amanda Lyle and Amanda Neil. I start typing "Am" and the records won't be shown in auto complete list unless I have already used them (on some particular entity save). I want to see all records starting with "Am" whether I have recently used/saved them.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not the way CRM 2011 is designed. The only way to get it to show all the contacts, is to click the lookup button.

If you wanted to change this functionality, you'd have to create a custom control.

Note: if you type in a valid choice, it will still auto-resolve to the record even if it doesn't show in the recent list. If you type in a partial, it should give you a list of suggestions as well.